# Count with a basic query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I´m doing a paging query with a simple filter, it´s working like a charm.

```
var result = client.Search<MyMetaData>(
    x => x.Index("MyIndex")
          .Type("MyType")
          .QueryString(filtro)
          .From(from)
          .Size(size)
);
```

But I need to know the number of results without paging to inform users.
I´m trying to do with the `Count` method, but without success.

Comment: probably i'm understanding the question wrong but if you simply want the total number of matches for the filter quer you could use the "total" field in the response from elasticsearch which returns the total matches ..wont that work?

Comment: I forgot this field, its working now, tks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES you can use the "Size" field to limit the number of records returned but the "Total" field will always have the correct total on the server even if only 100 records are returned (as with my sample below).

```
var result = ElasticClient.Search<PackingConfigES>(x => 
                x.Size(100)
                .MatchAll()
                );
            var totalResults = result.Total;
```